# Deformations of a map corresponding to a torsion section of the normal sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Given a map $f: C\rightarrow X$ from a curve to a variety, where the induced map $T_C\rightarrow f^{*}T_X$ is injective, there is a bijection between $H^{0}(N_f)$ and first order deformations of the map $f$ with fixed target and varying domain.

At a point $p\in C$ where $f$ is not an immersion, $N_f$ jumps in rank, and so has torsion supported at $p$.

If I know my section $s\in H^{0}(N_f)$ is contained in the torsion part of $N_f$, does that say anything about the deformation?